# Clang does not find function instantiated after function definition in template context

Tags: c++, clang

I have been experimenting with code derived from the "C++ Seasoning" presentation by Sean Parent, and have boiled my problem down to the following code:

```
#include <memory>

struct container {
    struct concept {
        virtual ~concept() {}
        virtual void foo_() = 0;
    };

    template <class T> struct model : concept {
        model (T x) : data_(x) {}

        void foo_() {
            foo(data_); // Line 13
        }

        T data_;
    };

    template <class T>
    container(T x) : self_(new model<T>(x)) {} // Line 20

    std::unique_ptr<concept> self_;

    friend void foo(container &c) { c.self_->foo_(); }
};

void foo(int i) // Line 27
{
}

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    container c(i); // Line 34
    foo(c);
}
```

The problem I have is that this code that compiles with g++, and yet not with Clang.

Clang gives me the following error messages:

```
prio.cpp:13:13: error: call to function 'foo' that is neither visible in the
      template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
            foo(data_);
            ^
prio.cpp:20:32: note: in instantiation of member function
      'container::model<int>::foo_' requested here
    container(T x) : self_(new model<T>(x)) {}
                               ^
prio.cpp:34:15: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'container::container<int>' requested here
    container c(i);
              ^
prio.cpp:27:6: note: 'foo' should be declared prior to the call site
void foo(int i)
     ^
```

My understanding is that overload resolution during templates occurs at the point of instantiation.  In this case, that is line 34 (as marked above.)  At this point, the global "foo" function is known.  And yet, it appears not to resolve.

Note for posterity: This was with Clang built from trunk on 14/Jan/14

Is this a bug in Clang then, or with g++?

Comment: That is an extension of g++. The name `foo` in `foo(data_)` is a dependent name, as `data_` is dependent on the template parameter. So argument-dependent lookup is deferred until the point of instantiation. However, argument-dependent lookup for `int` won't find *any* functions, as there are no namespaces and classes associated with fundamental types.

Comment: @dyp Ok, but even if I change foo(int) to foo(std::vector<int>) (and the variable in main appropriately), the error is still the same (with int replaced by std::vector<...>.)  Or have I totally misunderstood what you said?

Comment: Also tried putting foo() in a namespace and calling it appropriately, but then neither g++ nor clang accept it, both bailing out without even needing to instantiate model<T> at all.

Comment: @dyp: Most of what you mention in the comment is correct, although I am not sure whether the conclusion is. The fact that the lookup is deferred to the second phase does not mean that only ADL will be used. An identifier resolved in the second phase will  be looked up in the context of the template definition *and* ADL at the point of instantiation. The question here is whether this should compile: `struct T { voif f() { g(1); }; friend void g(int); };` (note that I completely removed the templates). Both gcc and clang reject that, although I am not sure they should...

Comment: @dyp: Rereading my comment, I am not sure I was clear. That ADL won't find it is correct, it is the core issue. But this is *not* and extension in gcc for templates and is completely unrelated to first or second phase lookup. [BTW, the compiler doing weird things with lookup in templates is VS, not gcc]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Oh, I was in a hurry and didn't even see the friend declaration -- as `data_` is of type `int`, even if the friend declaration could be found, the global one shouldn't. So the question only is if it's an illegal conversion or a name lookup fail.

Comment: @KazDragon Note that Sean Parent uses a *user-defined* type in his talk. That is, he doesn't put an `int` but some `struct document { /*...*/ };` into the container (IIRC). ADL simply finds nothing for fundamental types such as `int`, and it only finds `namespace std` (reliably) for `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gcc is wrong in this case, the code should *not* compile; but this is completely unrelated to the template. Friend declarations are particular in that they provide a declaration for a namespace level entity, but the declaration is not *visible* for normal lookup until a namespace declaration is also seen by the compiler.

Consider the simplified example:

```
struct X {
   friend void f(int);   // [1]
   void g() { f(1); }    // [2]
};
void h() { f(1); }       // [3]
void f(int);             // [4]
void i() { f(1); }       // [5]
```

The friend declaration [1] inside the `X` class provides a declaration for a namespace level function `f` taking an `int`, **but** that declaration is not visible at namespace level until a namespace level declaration is present in [4]. Both [2] and [3] will fail to compile, although [5] will compile since at that point the compiler will have parsed the function declaration.

So how can the declaration in [1] be used by the compiler to resolve a call? In this particular case *never*. The friend declaration can only be found by argument dependent lookup, but ADL will only look inside `X` if one of the arguments to the function call is of type `X`. In this case, the function does not have any argument `X`, so lookup will *never* use the `friend` declaration for anything other than lifting the restrictions of access to the variables of `X`.

That is:

```
struct Y {
   friend void f(int) {}
};
```

Without a latter namespace level declaration for `f` will declare and define a function that cannot be used anywhere in your program (lookup won't ever find it).

The simple workaround for your problem is to provide a declaration for the function at namespace level before the definition of the class:

```
#include <memory>

void foo(int);
struct container { // ...
```

Comment: After all that, I'm not sure it's relevant, but in my example, the friend function *does* take X, not int.  The foo outside the class is not the befriended function; just a similar-looking one.  Indeed, it seems that the friend function foo(container) is found just fine.  Nevertheless, this may well be correct.  I note that changing foo(int) to foo(vector<container>) (and adding appropriate move/forwards) does actually work.

Comment: @KazDragon: Same difference, you do need to provide a declaration of the function before you can use it.

Comment: Ok, I have just tested, and yes, if you create a UDT in a namespace and use that instead of int, then it works just fine.  So it's all about ADL.  I can work with that.  A satisfying conclusion.